# How to disable the complete formgroup at creation with FormBuilder?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm building a Fromgroup with the FormBuilder.

Example:

```
  formName = this.fb.group({
    inputName: ['default value', Validators.required],
    // many other items
  });
```

(Example from: https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-reactive-formbuilder)

Now based on a condition, I want this form to be disabled when loading the vie. Currently I'm using

```
if([Condition]) {
   formName.disable();
}
```

However this are three extra lines of code an I want to pass the disable argument when creating the form group, like it can be done with FormControls. Can this be done?

Comment: No. According to https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#controls, the only way to disable the form group is to call the `disable` method on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms created via `FormsBuilder` require you to use the `disable()` method in order to have it disabled.

Personally, in these scenariouses, I wrap the form with a container div and use an additional property that marks that the form is being loaded (or that we haven't finished yet).
Then, I use the property in an `*ngIf` to physically remove the whole form and display a spinner o something similar.

Alternatively, I use the property to control the CSS that disables the container div in a more clever way. The CSS depends on your context.